# Translating "Pacis puella" into Latin

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

*Pacis puella*: I found somewhere this meant "*for my family I live*", I used it, but now I can't find anything close to these words. Help.

Comment: http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/954/how-to-say-i-live-for-my-family-in-latin

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where did you find this translation? Some more details would improve the question and help us help you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately I've downvoted your question; if you edit it to give a little more context and especially to show us what work you've done on your own I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

*Pacis puella* literally means "girl of peace"; I have no idea how that could be translated as living for one's family. As Christianus mentioned in a comment, better translations of that motto have been posted at [this other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/954/how-to-say-i-live-for-my-family-in-latin).